# C# if textbox is empty, skip or add to list

Tags: c#, string, list, textbox, tryparse

I have been doing a lot of different research on this and from what I have found out, tryparse and parse does not exist for strings. So I am looking for an alternative for this.

I have 7 different textboxes and when the button is clicked I need it to check the textboxes (the variable is a string) and if the textbox is empty, I want it to completley skip it. If there is a string in the textbox, I want it to add it to a list. It doesn't have to be a list, I would prefer a list but I am not going to be picky! Pretty much the best possible way. I have 7 other checkboxes that are float values, and this is what I have with that:

```
List<float> ListGrade = new List<float>();

float LG;

if (float.TryParse(txtGrade1.Text, out LG))
    ListGrade.Add(LG);

if (float.TryParse(txtGrade2.Text, out LG))
    ListGrade.Add(LG);

if (float.TryParse(txtGrade3.Text, out LG))
    ListGrade.Add(LG);

if (float.TryParse(txtGrade4.Text, out LG))
    ListGrade.Add(LG);

if (float.TryParse(txtGrade5.Text, out LG))
    ListGrade.Add(LG);

if (float.TryParse(txtGrade6.Text, out LG))
    ListGrade.Add(LG);

if (float.TryParse(txtGrade7.Text, out LG))
    ListGrade.Add(LG);
```

That works perfect, but I can not figure it out for a string. I thought about using the nullorwhitespace, but I am not sure how to skip the textbox completely. I have never used a list before and this is the first time, and I am not completely understanding the out keyword. Every time I do a search, nothing comes up besides saying if (textbox1.Text == "") but that isn't showing how to skip the textbox.

Also, using the above code, and another list that looks identical to that, except the textboxes are identical and the name is different, I get an error saying I am using an undeclared variable when using this code at the end of the above code:

```
if (ListGrades.Count > 0 && ListCredits.Count > 0)
    AverageGrade = ListGrades.Sum() / ListCredits.Sum();
```

Do I have to add an else statement on to that? When I do it works, but I am not sure what I could add so the end result would not get messed up.

If you guys need any more information, please let me know. I am trying to learn and do research, but I am stumped!

Thanks guys!

Comment: is this winform project?

Answer (score 1):

You can skip adding a value to a list by doing the following:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtbox.Text))
    // add to the list here
```

Here is information on the [out keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

> and if the textbox is empty, I want it to completley skip it

you can do this

```
if(!string.isNullorEmpty(txtbox.Text))
{
   //do what you want here
}
```

or if you want that there shouldn't be any whitespaces like tab, line breaks etc you should use this function

```
if(!string.isNullorWhiteSpace(txtbox.Text))
{
   //do what you want here
}
```

> I am not completely understanding the out keyword

The out keyword causes arguments to be passed by reference. This is like the ref keyword, except that ref requires that the variable be initialized before it is passed. To use an out parameter, both the method definition and the calling method must explicitly use the out keyword

> I get an error saying I am using an undeclared variable

Show the declaration of `ListCredits`. And `ListGrades` should be `ListGrade`. Note there is no s at the end

Answer (score 1):

Using LINQ:

```
var textboxes = new [] {
       txtCredit1, txtCredit2, txtCredit3, txtCredit4, 
       txtCredit5, txtCredit6, txtCredit7
};
var ListCredits = textboxes.Select(tb => tb.Text)
                            .Where(txt => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt))
                            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on the short-cutting nature of conditionals;  if the first part of an ANDed condition fails, the second part will not be executes.  This allow you to skip textboxes.

```
List<float> grades = new List<float>();

float grade;

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtGrade1.Text) && float.TryParse(txtGrade1.Text, out grade))
    grades.Add(grade);

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtGrade2.Text) && float.TryParse(txtGrade2.Text, out grade))
    grades.Add(grade);

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtGrade3.Text) && float.TryParse(txtGrade3.Text, out grade))
    grades.Add(grade);

...

if (grades.Count > 0 && credits.Count > 0)
     averageGrade = grades.Sum() / credits.Sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with the following ways:

```
1. if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtbox.Text)){add to list}
2. if(textbox.text!="" && textbox.text!=null){add to list}
```

Thanks.